# How to install template SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database without the Internet?

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-4

My PC does not have a connection to the Internet. However, I would like to use a template(SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database) in my VS 2010. Is it possible to install this template without the Internet? How to do it? I have a flashcard.

Answer (score 1):

In short; you will need a connection to the internet. Once established, you can install web components (which includes SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database and the toolkit).